# Use of na.rm=True and na.action=na.pass in aggregate() - difference?

Tags: r, na, na.rm

I couldn't find a question here on Stack overflow that already answers my question so I'm very sorry if this has already been asked and I just couldn't find it.

All in all, this question is more about understanding what happens with my data depending what code I use.

So, I have a dataset with a few NAs in it.

I want to aggregate the data and use `na.rm=True` which tells R to ignore the NAs while calculating, right?
The output I received included NAs and this lead to me using the function `na.action=na.pass` together with `na.rm=True`.
This left me with significantly less NAs in my output.
To be honest I don't understand why...

As I like to try out and find out for myself, I looked at different variations of my aggregate function:

1. only with `na.rm=True`
2. only with `na.action=na.pass`
3. `na.rm=True`, `na.action=na.pass`

only using 2. I get a lot of NAs, which makes sense because I told R to include all NAs in the calculation without having `na.rm=True` in it.
At the same time 1. and 3. don't give me the same results. why is that?

I thought that the two `na.rm=True` and `na.action=na.pass` mean the same thing... apparently they don't, because I get slightly different values for my variables' means.

**What happens with my data when I use both na.rm=True and `na.action=na.pass` in an aggregate function, compared to only using `na.rm=True`. Which is better to be used?**

Thank you very much, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you have example data to share?

Comment: @Ronak Shah Sadly, I cannot share data, because it's confidential... I just need to know what difference it makes when using <na.rm=T, na.action=na.pass> compared to just <na.rm=T> with an aggregate function... but thank you already for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a simple example to understand this :

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 2, 1, 3, NA, NA), b = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3))
df
#   a b
#1  2 1
#2  2 1
#3  1 1
#4  3 2
#5 NA 2
#6 NA 3
```

- Using `aggregate` with `sum`.

```
aggregate(a~b, df, sum)

#  b a
#1 1 5
#2 2 3
```

Notice that there is no `b = 3` row in the output. Also `b = 2` has 1 `NA` value but we it returned output of 3 without adding `na.rm = TRUE`. It means that by default all the `NA` values are dropped while calculating.

- With `na.action = 'na.pass'`.

```
aggregate(a~b, df, sum, na.action = 'na.pass')

#  b  a
#1 1  5
#2 2 NA
#3 3 NA
```

By specifying `na.action = na.pass` we ask it to include all the `NA` values. Hence we now have a row for `b = 3` and `b = 2` is `NA` since we did not include `na.rm = TRUE`.

- Using `na.rm = TRUE`.

```
aggregate(a~b, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = 'na.pass')

#  b a
#1 1 5
#2 2 3
#3 3 0
```

I think output of this should be self-explanatory.